# Which OO design to use when there is a limitation from a third-party system?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Imagine this scenario: 
A Customer object that is provided by a third-party system which have multiple properties related to phone numbers.

```
public class Customer {

    private String phoneAreaCode;
    private String phoneNumber;

}
```

Another third-party system which receive his own Customer object which have a Phone object inside it.

```
public class XCustomer {

    private Phone phone;

}
```

I would like to know if there is a OO design pattern to convert the Customer to XCustomer. Should one of the Customers know about the other Customer object and convert the phone properties into a Phone object? Should I create utility classes to convert one into another? Or there is a better solution?

Comment: If they're both third-party classes, they won't know about each other, so you don't really have a choice. If one of them is not a third-party class, it's up to you to decide if you want to couple it with the third-party API or not. You generally don't.

Comment: The model is provided by the third-party system but we have a representation of that model in our own project. As you commented, we could couple them, but I don't think that is a good approach and I was thinking if there is already a pattern for this problem.

Comment: Of course, in proper OO design the code that *receives* an object would define an *interface* (that you can implement yourself on anything), not a specific class.

Comment: @Bergi, Just to confirm if I understood what you said. In this example, we would define a Customer Interface, choose an approach for the Phone object and on each specification of Customer we would convert from their Phone standard to our custom Interface?

Comment: @Smaniotto No, *they* should have defined a standard `XCustomer` (and possibley `Phone`) interface, then you could provide a custom implementation (such as your own `MyCustomerWrapper` around object provided by the first system) and pass it to their API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since both Customer and CustomerX classes come from third party so you can't modify Customer and CustomerX class.
2. I prefer a simple utility to do the conversion.
3. You can create Converter interface/implementation. This will be useful in DI environment or you want to have multi implementations

   ```
   public interface CustomerConverter {

       CustomerX convert(Customer customer);          
   }

   public class CustomerConverterImpl implements CustomerConverter {

        @Override
        public CustomerX convert(Customer customer) {
            // TODO convert
        }
   }
   ```